# Removing an object from a vector by index

Tags: c++, vector

I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
for (int i = Particles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (Particles[i].Dead) {
        Particles.erase(Particles.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get this error:

> Error C2280   'Particle &Particle::operator =(const Particle &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
>   Gravity   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility 2518

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here's the particle code.

**Header file**

```
class Particle
{
public:
    const float G = 6.674 * pow(10, -11);
    float Mass, Radius;
    Vector2 Position, Velocity, Force;
    bool Dead = false;

    void Gravity(Particle Particle2);
    void Move();
    void Draw(SDL_Surface *Surface, Uint32 Color);

    Particle(float MassBounds[2], Vector2 PositionBounds[2], float Density);
    Particle::Particle(float Mass, Vector2 Position, float Density, bool NonRandom);
    Particle();
};
```

**Source file**

```
void Particle::Gravity(Particle Particle2)
{
    float GravityMagnitude = (Particle::G*Mass*Particle2.Mass) / Vector2::DistanceSquared(Position, Particle2.Position);
    Force += (Particle2.Position - Position).Normalised()*GravityMagnitude;
}

void Particle::Move()
{
    Velocity += Force/Mass;
    Position += Velocity;
}

void Particle::Draw(SDL_Surface *Surface, Uint32 Color)
{
    if (int(Radius) > 0) { SDLDrawFilledCircle(Surface, int(Position.x), int(Position.y), Radius<1?1:int(Radius), Color); }
}

Particle::Particle(float MassBounds[2], Vector2 PositionBounds[2], float Density)
{
    Mass = RandRange(MassBounds);
    Position = Vector2(RandRange(PositionBounds[0].x, PositionBounds[1].x), RandRange(PositionBounds[0].y, PositionBounds[1].y));
    Radius = pow((3.0 * Mass) / (4 * M_PI*Density), 1.0 / 3.0);
    Velocity = Vector2();
    Force = Vector2();
}
Particle::Particle(float Mass, Vector2 Position, float Density, bool NonRandom)
{
    this->Mass = Mass;
    this->Position = Position;
    Radius = pow((3.0 * Mass) / (4 * M_PI*Density), 1.0 / 3.0);
    Velocity = Vector2();
    Force = Vector2();
}
Particle::Particle()
{
    Mass = 1;
    Position = Vector2();
    Radius = 1;
    Velocity = Vector2();
    Force = Vector2();
}

inline bool operator==(const Particle& a, const Particle& b) { return a == b; }
```

Comment: You've left something out of the question. The error message says that `Particle`'s `operator=` function is deleted, but your header file shows no evidence of that.

Comment: Do objects in C++ not have default = and == operators? I thought they did, but please correct me if i am wrong, as i didnt think i'd need one since i wouldnt be doing a special comparison or set

Comment: The assignment operator (operator=) is defined automatically and must be explicitly deleted. The equality operator (operator==) is never defined by default.

Comment: AFAIK, I haven't explicitly deleted the operator=, do I need to do this?

Comment: @QFSW Look at your class carefully and think about why it may not be assignable. You still should post a [mcve]. There is too much irrelevant code here.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using remove_if and erase:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Vector {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool is_negative (Vector a) {
    return a.x < 0 && a.y < 0;
}

int main() {
    vector<Vector> vectors;
    vectors.push_back({-1, -2});
    vectors.push_back({-1, 2});
    vectors.push_back({1, 2});
    vectors.push_back({-1, -2});
    vectors.erase(
        std::remove_if(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(), is_negative),
        vectors.end());

    for (auto v : vectors) {
        cout << v.x << " " << v.y << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the error in the question means, and how this helps?

Comment: Tried this, still the same error :(
Although I agree that if we get them to work, this will be a better approach

Answer (score -1):

I could not help notice this in your for loop:

```
Particles.erase(Particles.begin() + i-1)
```

More importantly

```
i - 1
```

You start with

```
i = Particles.size() - 1
```

and do not stop until

```
i < 0
```

This

```
Particles.begin()
```

gives you the head of the list.
When

```
i == 0  

Particles.begin() + (i - 1)
```

will try to get invalid node.
Which translates to

```
 Particles.begin() - 1
```

I do not know when your code breaks, I am going based on your loop

Here is link w/doc  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Hope this helps